# Manually disable notification in terminal

Tags: terminal, macos, notifications

I searched for this, and maybe there's some technical language I am missing or don't understand, but cannot figure it out from previous posts.

I moved all autodesk applications to the trash and emptied it, but I still get more than 5 notifications a day that my A360 account is expiring and my files won't be synced, etc. When I click the notification, nothing happens.

The application is not in SystemPreferences>Notifications, so I cannot disable them from there. How can I (1) find the notification from this app no longer on my computer and then (2) disable it? I'm thinking I'll have to use the terminal, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: It sounds like you trashed Autodesk and it is still harassing you. Are you asking how do you delete your Autodesk Software completely? You might not need to use terminal per say.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of that notification and a screenshot of your menu bar? I suspect that you have moved the app to trash but, the helper app is still running thus you are getting notifications.